# Levi-Civita connections and gradient

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections, hessian-matrix

I have the exercise to show for a Riemannian manifold $M$ and Levi-Civita-con $\nabla$, that

$g(\operatorname{grad}_gf,\operatorname{grad}_gf)=c\in \mathbb{R}$ implies $\nabla_{\operatorname{grad}_gf}\operatorname{grad}_gf =0$

Now I use that for $\operatorname{Hess}_g(f)(X,Y):= X(Y(f))-(\nabla_X Y)(f)$ it holds:

1) $\operatorname{Hess}_g(f)(X,Y)=\operatorname{Hess}_g(f)(Y,X)$ and

2) $\operatorname{Hess}_g(f)(X,Y)=g(\nabla_X\operatorname{grad}_gf,Y)$

What I have so far: I want to show that $g(\nabla_{\operatorname{grad}_gf}\operatorname{grad}_gf,X)=0$ for all $X$.

$g(\nabla_{\operatorname{grad}_gf}\operatorname{grad}_gf,X)=\operatorname{Hess}_g(f)(\operatorname{grad}_gf,X) (b)= \operatorname{Hess}_g(f)(X,\operatorname{grad}_g f) (a)= X(\operatorname{grad}_gf(f))-\nabla_X \operatorname{grad}_g f(f)$

Now I use $\operatorname{grad}_gf(f)= g(\operatorname{grad}_gf,\operatorname{grad}_gf)=c$ which implies that

$X(\operatorname{grad}_gf(f))-\nabla_X \operatorname{grad}_g f(f)=-\nabla_X \operatorname{grad}_g f(f)$

But now I don't know how to show that $-\nabla_X \operatorname{grad}_g f(f)=0$.

Is my approach correct? And if yes, how can I show that $-\nabla_X \operatorname{grad}_g f(f)=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Yf=df\ Y=({\rm grad}\ f,Y)$ so that $Yf=0$ iff $Y\perp {\rm grad}\
f$

Here $(\nabla_X {\rm grad} f,{\rm grad}\ f)=0$ so that $ \nabla_X
{\rm grad}\ f$ is orthogonal to ${\rm grad}\ f$.

Comment: But how do we know that $(\nabla_X \text{grad} f, \text{grad} f)=0$?

Comment: We have an assumption that $|{\rm grad}\ f|$ is const.

Comment: Oh, do I conclude right that:  Since $\nabla $ is a Levi-Civita connection, I know $(\nabla_X\text{grad f}, \text{grad f})=X(c)-(\nabla_X\text{grad f}, \text{grad f})=-(\nabla_X\text{grad f}, \text{grad f})$?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me a lot!